# Update table header regarding file name

Tags: text-processing, columns, csv-simple

I have several files named has follow (I just give 2 names as examples)(note: they have a semi colon `;` field separator):

```
component1_component2_component3.csv
```

e.g.

```
almourol_gfdl_85.csv
almourol_had_85.csv
```

Each of this tables are organize as follow:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;WFDisi;SWIM;GAP3;HYPE;VIC
1971;01;01;1206.1;627;1252.6;909;357.6
1971;01;02;1303.4;654.3;1397.4;916;478.5
1971;01;03;1248.9;662;1318.8;951;653.1
```

The first three columns are always the same but the number of columns can change and sometimes the tables are as follow:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;ECOMAG;HYPE
1971;01;01;4138.3;4390
1971;01;02;4129;4380
1971;01;03;4115.9;4370
```

For all those tables I would like to change the header by implementing the second component of the file name. So for the two "real life" example here enclosed the desired output should look like this:

example1:
- file name: `almourol_gfdl_85.csv`
- desired output:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;GFDL_WFDisi;GFDL_SWIM;GFDL_GAP3;GFDL_HYPE;GFDL_VIC
1971;01;01;1206.1;627;1252.6;909;357.6
1971;01;02;1303.4;654.3;1397.4;916;478.5
1971;01;03;1248.9;662;1318.8;951;653.1
```

example2:
- file name: `almourol_had_85.csv`
- desired output:

```
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;HAD_ECOMAG;HAD_HYPE
1971;01;01;4138.3;4390
1971;01;02;4129;4380
1971;01;03;4115.9;4370
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to:

- split the filename into underscore delimited fields
- prepend the second field of the filename to the fourth and greater header fields, in upper case

In `awk`:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=FS} 
  FNR==1 {
    split(FILENAME,a,"_"); 
    for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) $i = sprintf("%s_%s", toupper(a[2]), $i)}1
' *85.csv
```

e.g.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=";"; OFS=FS} FNR==1 {split(FILENAME,a,"_"); for (i=4; i<=NF; i++) $i = sprintf("%s_%s", toupper(a[2]), $i)}1' *85.csv
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;GFDL_WFDisi;GFDL_SWIM;GFDL_GAP3;GFDL_HYPE;GFDL_VIC
1971;01;01;1206.1;627;1252.6;909;357.6
1971;01;02;1303.4;654.3;1397.4;916;478.5
1971;01;03;1248.9;662;1318.8;951;653.1
YEAR;MONTH;DAY;HAD_ECOMAG;HAD_HYPE
1971;01;01;4138.3;4390
1971;01;02;4129;4380
1971;01;03;4115.9;4370
```